# How to get current or set wanted regional format in the terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, locale, 16.04

I'm looking for single line terminal commands to:

- check my current regional format or
- set the regional format to English US.

Currently to change this I have to go to Settings->Language Support->Regional Formats

(Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, should preferably also work in 16.04 LTS)

Comment: I don't know why you ask this, but in my case I need to know because the language support freezes when I try to change the regional formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regional Formats changes the following variables:

```
LC_NUMERIC
LC_TIME
LC_MONETARY
```

You can use `locale` to check the current set format.

```
ron@ron:~$ locale
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

If you want to see all the locale available in your system you can use:

```
ron@ron:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
```

To change, for example, the date format to US you can use:

```
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

To change it permanently:

```
sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

You can also manually edit the file `/etc/default/locale` instead of `update-locale`, if you wish so. Changes will be applied the next time you log-in.

Refer to [Locale - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) for more details. `man 5 locale` will you more options to find-tune any of the formats.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed some strange behavior: initially all the variables in `/etc/default/locale` were set to `nl_BE.UTF-8` except `LANG`, which was set to `en_US.UTF-8`. The command `sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` did what I expected. But when I tried to set the regional format in the Ubuntu settings window, `locale` was still the same as before.

Comment: There are more variables than those you mention which are changed when you set Regional Format via Language Support.

Answer (score 4):

This command sets regional formats to en_US.UTF-8 in the same manner as Language Support:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Accounts /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User$UID org.freedesktop.Accounts.User.SetFormatsLocale string:'en_US.UTF-8'
```

It updates your user setting in accountsservice and the file `~/.pam_environment`.

`/etc/default/locale` is updated by Language Support only if you click the *Apply System-Wide* button.

Haven't figured out the corresponding command to check the current format.

Can't help wondering why you want to do it. It's normally not a good idea to mess with these settings manually on an Ubuntu deskop. Language Support does the right thing.

Comment: Why: 
1) I like the terminal, 
2) I had a problem with a third party xml parser that didn't parse floating points correctly because of the dot/comma difference for numeric notations. Changing the regional format for LC_NUMERIC from nl_BE to en_US fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You could check the LANGUAGE variable in your shell with:

```
echo $LANGUAGE
```

The output for my system running GB English is:

```
en_GB:en
```