# How can I set Region & Language format from command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome, language-support

I tried `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, but it does not change the **Format**.

What I do manually to fix it:

- Open settings
- Go to **Region & Language**
- From **Formats**, select the current format
- From **Formats** dialog, search for *United States* and select it
- Click **Done**
- Reboot

How can I automate it via command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current or set wanted regional format in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754345/how-to-get-current-or-set-wanted-regional-format-in-the-terminal) Please see my answer to that question. The approved answer does not work reliably.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, you **long** command literally did it. Thank you so much.